# Is Rubocop a superset of the "ruby -c" syntax check?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

We had a test that found every Ruby file in our application and ran `ruby -c` on it. We introduced [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) and made it check the same list of files.

Is the test that ran `ruby -c` actually now useless, or is there an example of a failure mode that would be caught by `ruby -c` but not Rubocop?

The documentation for `ruby -c` says:

> Causes Ruby to check the syntax of the script and exit without executing. If there are no syntax errors, Ruby will print "Syntax OK" to the standard output.

This is an example of a syntax issue that will be caught by either:

```
% echo "puts 'hello world" > hot_script.rb
% ruby -c hot_script.rb
hot_script.rb:1: unterminated string meets end of file

% rubocop hot_script.rb
Inspecting 1 file
F

Offenses:

hot_script.rb:1:6: F: unterminated string meets end of file
(Using Ruby 1.9 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
puts 'hello world
     ^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected
```

Rubocop even catches some of the same warnings, though I didn't have `ruby -c` configured to catch these previously, and I am therefore more interested in errors. Here's an example of relative parity in handling a warning:

```
% cat unused_var.rb
def hot_method
  a = 1
  b = 2
  puts b
end

% ruby -cwW2 unused_var.rb
unused_var.rb:2: warning: assigned but unused variable - a
Syntax OK

% rubocop unused_var.rb
Inspecting 1 file
W

Offenses:

unused_var.rb:2:3: W: Lint/UselessAssignment: Useless assignment to variable - a.
  a = 1
  ^

1 file inspected, 1 offense detected
```

I searched using

- https://www.google.com/search?q=rubocop%20syntax%20check%20superset
- https://www.google.com/search?q=is%20there%20any%20reason%20to%20run%20ruby%20-c%20syntax%20check%20if%20i%20use%20rubocop

but I may be doing it wrong. The test is way slower in Ruby 1.9 than it was in Ruby 1.8, so the answer to this question is actually valuable to me. And you have to admit, you're curious, right?

Comment: Rubocop checks for best practices, line-length, and complexity, things that `ruby -c` won't do. The docs say "Out of the box it will enforce many of the guidelines outlined in the community [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)." Using `ruby -cwW2` would be more comprehensive as it'll warn of unused variables which is useful to catch misspelled variable names.

Comment: The Tin Man is a rubiest! I would have accepted this as an answer, even though I'm especially interested in an actual syntax error counterexample, but I added an example showing that rubocop is actually catching some unused variable issues these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "most of the time." RuboCop builds on the parser gem, which is a standalone Ruby parser which mimics, more or less, the MRI parser. RuboCop wraps parser's syntax checks and will properly report issues. However, as stated on the parser's GitHub:

> Unfortunately MRI often changes syntax in patch level versions
>   [...] there is no simple way to track these changes.
>
> This policy makes it all but impossible to make Parser precisely
>   compatible with the Ruby MRI parser.

In addition, parser supports the latest minor version of whatever release you are using, and doesn't backport minor versions. So if you use Ruby 2.4.0, RuboCop will use a parser version supporting 2.4.1 syntax.

For all intents and purposes, parser is equivalent to the official MRI parser, and unless you have a specific reason to use both, using RuboCop alone should be sufficient.

Comment: i've upvoted both answers. i'm accepting this one since it's more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Rubocop will also identify and report syntax errors since the code cannot be properly parsed if that is the case, so there's no need for both.

Comment: This has been my anecdotal experience. But for some reason I don't want to believe it is true, and think someone will come up with an example of where ruby -c is superior. If no one does in a day or two, I will definitely accept this, thank you!

Comment: @burnettk It's theoretically possible, but that would be a bug. Besides, any parse errors that get through would be caught by your test suite anyway since tests can't run on code that can be parsed.